# Объединить метки про устройства

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Три метки об одном и том же: [устройство](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be), [устройства](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0), и [внешние-устройства](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0) это явное излишество.

[внешние-устройства](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0) описывает тематику максимально конкретно, её бы и оставить.

UPD в ответ на комментарий.

Внешние устройства это вообще-то не только портативные HDD, традиционно это периферия в широком смысле. То есть устройства, внешние относительно процессора.

Но пусть так. Тогда может вместо [устройство](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be) и [устройства](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0) ввести новую метку [периферия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f), а [внешние-устройства](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0) пусть остается за ардуино и проч.?

Comment: Посмотрел на enso о чём у них [метка](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/device/info). Это как всякие внешние HDD, так и смартфоны и ардуинки

Comment: @A K, дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Устройства бывают не только внешними.

Comment: @Qwertiy, внутренние устройства это очень специфичный класс. Системный таймер, контроллеры шин, что-нибудь еще в этом роде. Тот же системный диск, к примеру, это внешнее устройство, даже если физически он в корпусе компьютера, а не в отдельной коробке.

Answer (score 4):

1. Метки у нас не выдумывают. Все решения принимаются (как правило), на основе того, как они используются. По [периферия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f) ноль вопросов, значит её никто не использует. Создавать такую метку и форсить людей её использовать - не самое лучшее решение.
2. По [устройство](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be) всего 4 вопроса. В двух из них речь вообще не про устройство как *device*, а про устройство как *internal structure*.
3. **Я бы [устройство](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be) синонимизировал к [устройства](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0) для начала.**
4. Есть ещё встраиваемые системы (*embedded system*). Их относить будем к [внешние-устройства](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0)?